# prevent selecting holidays date in calendar on registration form

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, asp.net-ajax

I am using code snippet plugin in wordpress and I just disabled the previous dates in calendar on registration form.
Check pick up date on this form.
http://bdsbarcelona.com/request-service-form/
I have used following code to disable previous dates, now I want disable selected holidays from calendar. for example I am goind on holidays for 9 days so I want that 9 dates to be disabled in calendar.

```
add_action('frm_date_field_js', 'limit_my_date_field');
    function limit_my_date_field($field_id){
      if($field_id == 'field_3jztsi'){ //change FIELDKEY to the key of your date field
        echo ',minDate:0,maxDate:+365';
      }
      if($field_id == 'field_3jztsi2'){ //change FIELDKEY to the key of your date field
        echo ',minDate:0,maxDate:+365';
      }
    }
```

Comment: This isn't n Angular question

Comment: That was just a tag, because may be any angular expert can solve this problem